# If page is enabled, show div

Tags: conditional, status

I'd like to show a 'Jobs' link in my navigation only if the Jobs page is enabled. Is there a way for craft to detect if the page is enabled, and show a div?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check the status of an entry with `.status`. https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#status

This code should work!

```
{% set jobsEntry = craft.entries.id(jobsId) %}

{% if jobsEntry.status == 'live' %}
    <a href="{{ jobsEntry.url }}">Jobs</a>
{% else  %}
    Jobs is disabled
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks! The code definitely works, but my link still shows even though I disabled the entry. And the page still shows up even though the entry's status is disabled. I thought marking it as 'disabled' would at least not let it show in the browser.

Comment: That sounds strange – when you specifically ask only for entries that are `live`, it shouldn't show entries that are `disabled`. Do you have any active caching going on?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem where if a page was 'disabled', I didn't want it to show in my footer navigation. The recommended answer didn't work for me. The link still showed up. The following worked:

```
{% set myEntry = craft.entries.id(entryId).first() %}

{% if myEntry %}
    <li><a href="example.com">Example</a></li>
{% endif %}
```